# Unable to Compare Return of Len w/ User Defined Int

Tags: python, typeerror

Was unable to find an answer to this specific scenario, apologies if I missed it.

Attempting to define a function wherein a text file is read, words are stripped and written to str, and words with length of user defined range are displayed.

File: "Hello", "Hi", "Greetings", "Hola"

Range: Min: 3 Max: 5

Output: "Hello", "Hi", "Hola"

When comparing len of the words to the min and max value input, I am receiving error:

**TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'**

Code snippet:

```
    with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            print(word)
            print(len(word))
            if len(word) >= smallest_word and len(word) <= largest_word:
                word_list.append(word)
```

I was certain len returns type int, am I incorrect? Perhaps something else I am overlooking?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Where are min and max defined? (And note, these are already the names of built in functions, which you are shadowing. You should use different names.)

Comment: Good point! I will change those. They are defined in main() with user input.

Comment: But the point is that it is those that appear to be strings, which is why I asked to see their definitions.

Comment: You've answered my question in less than 5 minutes of posting. Silly mistake of not defining the user input as int instead of str. Talk about tunnel vision!

Answer (score 0):

Simply forgot to define user input as int. Defaulted input to str and len was properly returning int the whole time.

Changed:

```
    smallest_word = input("Please enter the minimum letter amount: ")
    largest_word = input("Please enter the maximum letter amount: ")
```

To:

```
    smallest_word = int(input("Please enter the minimum letter amount: "))
    largest_word = int(input("Please enter the maximum letter amount: "))
```